# Show Empty Categories on Catalog Page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalog, cataloginventory

I want to show all categories, even if they have no products in them.

How can I achieve something like this?

[image: Empty Category Example]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll need to override the `Magento/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml` template. Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
    <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
        <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
        <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
        <?php $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
        <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
            <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
            <dd class="filter-options-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter); ?></dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I believe that this line is what you will want to remove: `<?php if ($filter->getItemsCount(): ?>`. Obviously, override the core file, don't edit it directly.

If you have any questions, please let me know!

Comment: All that does is remove the entire "category type" from the block. I want the category children that are 0 to be visible.